# Storing points in an efficient way for future distance calculations

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, coding-efficiency

I ran into some discussion about an efficient algorithm which solves the following issue:

Suppose we have a map of points and there are some points which present a parking. There is one car in some specific point in the map that suddenly looking for a parking so it needs to find (for the sake of simplicity) the most 10 closest parking.

The questions are, **How to save the points in a clever way? in what order? relative to what? how to classify the distances?**

Clarifications:

1. Saving the points by cities, does not solve the problem cause maybe in the neighboring city there is a more close parking.
2. Naive algorithm is obviously and unwanted - check all distances.

Comment: That's a [nearest-neigbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), and some variant of an [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) may be a good fit.

Comment: Storing the latitude and longitude might be an efficient way for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to divide this area with squares and each square will store points(if it will be "small amount of points" (easy to compute) or 4 smaller squares containing points - by that you will be able to get easily closest point - by checking at most 4 squares. Also if this doesn't fit your needs I would recommend [Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) mentioned by [Yakov Galka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277176/yakov-galka) Also I would think about approaches made for example by Google (Maps), you can locate nearest gas station, etc, but I cannot find anything worth reading.